# Get Billing Email from WooCommece Checkout and Pass to Fullstory JS

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using WooCommerce on WordPress where I've integrated [**Fullstory**](http://fullstory.com) snippet in the header of my site.

I've enabled checkout for guests, that is, they can check out without creating an account on my website.

What I want to achieve is to get the name and email from the billing details of the customer from a successfully completed checkout form (i.e., new Order). I then need to pass this name and email to the [Fullstory.identify()](https://help.fullstory.com/develop-js/identify) method (in Javascript)that tags Fullstory sessions with user data.

How can I do that?

Fullstory has a [tutorial here](https://help.fullstory.com/integrate/wordpress) on how to integrate it with WordPress, but that is for logged in users (see snippet below). I need it for guests that are checking out.

```
...
})(window,document,'FS','script','user');

<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
var wpEmail = "<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->user_email; ?>";
var count = <?php echo wc_get_customer_order_count(get_current_user_id()); ?>;

FS.identify(wpEmail, { "displayName": wpEmail,
    "email": wpEmail,
    "orders_int": count });

<?php } ?>

</script>
```

Comment: Is this code on the success page, you should be able to grab the order information and pop it in the page with PHP

Comment: @Aravona how to grab the order email? will this be done through a hook/filter?

Comment: Possibly, it depends on the code - can you post what you've done?

Comment: @Aravona I've updated the question with the code. But again, that is just for logged in users.

Comment: Try adding an else to the if and see if you can get the `wpEmail` information still

Comment: @Aravona it wont return anything because there's no user logged in

Comment: Oh yes I see - sorry - what about retrieving the last order information instead of current user?

Comment: @Aravona That's precisely what I want to do, but how can I do that in Php?

Comment: If you're able to get the customer id on that page you should be able to use on of the WC functions to get the last order information of that user.